# How to insert new row with both existing data from another table and inputted values?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, static, insert, ssms

I'm trying to insert a row into a table, and in that row I want one column to contain data from a specific column in another table while also inserting static data into the same row. Something like this:

```
USE [someDatabase]
  INSERT INTO [some].[table] ([column1], [column2], [column3], [column4], [column5])
  SELECT [someColoum]
  FROM [another].[table]
  WHERE [aDifferentColumn] LIKE '%something%'
  VALUE ('static info', 'static info', 'static info', 'static info')
```

As you can see in this example I'm try to add a row into [some].[table] but I want [column1] to contain specific data from [someColumn] when [aDifferentColumn] it's LIKE '%something%', then I want the other columns to have static info. How might I do this? When I run this query I get:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like the following:

```
USE [someDatabase]
INSERT  INTO [some].[table]
        (
          [column1],
          [column2],
          [column3],
          [column4],
          [column5]
        )
        SELECT
          [someColoum],
          'static info',
          'static info',
          'static info',
          'static info'
        FROM
          [another].[table]
        WHERE
          [aDifferentColumn] LIKE '%something%'
```

Comment: @Will Anderson. NP. Pls accept it as the answer if it you're happy with it.